# mysql substituting one columns value for another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull students and the courses they are registered for from a mysql database.  I want to replace the course id with the course name in the output.

I have these tables and columns:

table: `users_to_courses`
columns: `users_LOGIN` and `courses_ID`

table: `users`
columns: `login`, `name` and `surname`

table: `courses`
columns: `id` and `name`

The tables tie together on the following:

```
users_to_courses.users_LOGIN = users.login 
users_to_courses.courses_ID = courses.id
```

I am trying to get output of surname, name, courses (by name and not id) so it would look like Smith, John  Chemistry, Physics, Composition

Here is what I am trying unsuccessfully:

```
SELECT
users.surname,
users.name,
users.login,
users_to_courses.users_LOGIN,
(select group_concat (courses.name) from courses
where users_to_courses.users_LOGIN = users.login and users_to_courses.courses_ID =    
courses.id
GROUP BY users.surname) as courses
from courses join users_to_courses
on courses.id = users_to_courses.courses_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select

    u.surname,
    u.name,
    u.login,
    uc.users_LOGIN,
    c.Name,

    --added this line
    group_concat (c.name)  
From users_to_courses uc
JOIN users u ON uc.users_LOGIN = u.login 
JOIN courses c ON uc.courses_ID = c.id

-- added this line
GROUP BY u.surname, u.name, u.login, uc.users_LOGIN
```

Comment: This works when I change c.CourseName to c.name.  I would still like to have all the courses grouped by surname.  Is is possible to add the group_concat to this query?

Comment: That gives me #1630 - FUNCTION gulllake_efront.group_concat does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @user1731399 I don't think that has something to do with the answer though but I have updated my answer replacing `courses.name` with `c.name` in the `group_concat` line

Comment: That didn't work either, but this provides the data I need even if it isn't grouped on one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.login, users.surname, users.name, courses.name
FROM users_to_courses
INNER JOIN users ON users_to_courses.users_LOGIN = users.login
INNER JOIN courses ON users_to_courses.courses_ID = courses.id
GROUP BY users_to_courses.users_LOGIN
```

It is not entirely clear how the users_to_courses table is organized, if it is one class per row entry, then you will end up with one row per class, but all the rows corresponding to the same user ID will be consecutive in the table...

If the users_to_courses.courses_ID entry is a list of multiple course ids this might not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT users.surname, users.name, users.login, users_to_courses.users_LOGIN from courses c 
 INNER JOIN users_to_courses uc ON  uc.courses_ID = c.id
 INNER JOIN login l ON uc.users_login = l.login
```

Comment: This produces this error: #1146 - Table 'gulllake_efront.login' doesn't exist